# How to export shapefile to DWG file with symbology

Tags: symbology, export, dwg

I can export shapefile to CAD file with symbology. I export polygon from ArcGIS desktop  to CAD file but I always exported without its symbology.

Is there any method to keep its symbology?

Comment: The `.shp` file does not contain any symbology. The symbology in ArcGIS is saved separately in `.lyr` format.
What software do you use to read `CAD` format files?

Comment: i use auto desk auto cad 2021 to read CAD file

Comment: @ComradeChe I think the question is more how to keep the symbology you have set in Arcmap when you export data in DWG/DXF format, (same as QGIS do, see https://www.qgis.ch/fr/projets/export-dxf). As ESRI  is partnering with autodesk one may expect that this is possible

Answer (score 1):

Esri documentation says this is not possible. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012813

I always hear about new esri/autodesk integrations so there may be other ways to ingest GIS data in Autocad without simply converting GIS to CAD.